# Youtube API with Retrofit2 not able to parse response(Error: PlaylistItemListResponse has type PageInfo got LinkedHashMap)

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use Youtube API with Retrfoit2 on Android but both Jackson/JSON converters are not able to parse objects.

YoutubeService

```
public interface YoutubeService {
    @GET("playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails")
    Observable<PlaylistItemListResponse> getVideos(@Query("maxResults") Integer maxResults,
                                               @Query("pageToken")String pageToken,
                                               @Query("playlistId")String playlistId,
                                               @Query("key")String key);
}
```

Here is how I am using it:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(YouTube.DEFAULT_BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    youtubeService = retrofit.create(YoutubeService.class);
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: field com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PlaylistItemListResponse.pageInfo has type com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PageInfo, got java.util.LinkedHashMap (through reference chain: com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PlaylistItemListResponse["pageInfo"])
```

[This](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/PlaylistItemListResponse.html) is model for PlaylistItemResponse

Java [files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3s2v1k6g90kcqls/AAAVWwKVL-yCX1T4mvZc27_4a?dl=0) for PlaylistItemResponse

[This](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b25e6ec0001161b1d11278cfb1c62f25) is response

Can someone guide me how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` instead of Jackson one? Because Google sometimes create their classes to work specifically with Gson

Comment: Yes, I tried that also but exact same error

Comment: canu plz put your model class

PlaylistItemListResponse?? full java file

Comment: Maybe you cant use an Observable in this case... the problem seems to happen in the RxJava. Have you tried removing the Observable part and the `addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())`? Let's try without observable and see if the response is parsed correctly and provide you a correct `PlaylistItemResponse` object

Comment: @VishalPatel Added java files also https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3s2v1k6g90kcqls/AAAVWwKVL-yCX1T4mvZc27_4a?dl=0

Comment: @bpsingh  plz check and if any problem tell me brifly

Comment: @bpsingh   have u any luck from below answer?

Comment: @VishalPatel sorry, I got stuck with something, will try and update you as soon as I get chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand deeper with your problem but try to change like below.

1.Make it With Gson

`addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`

2.change your model class `PlaylistItemListResponse` with below.

[Link of model class](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24790777/)

because its all about your model class issue.

Happy coding

Comment: it worked but do we have any clue on why google's model was not working?

Comment: i think its used for different things